# Self Encrypting Disc (SED) enabled SSD password / key requirements

Tags: ssd, security, encryption, passwords

Several `SSD` manufacturers have released Self Encrypting Disks (SEDs) which use `hardware encryption` on the disk.

This is `OS` agnostic, and should generally be faster than software based encryption like `LUKS-dmCrypt` or `Bitlocker` etc.

However, I could not clarify if such a disk, and encryption, if used, would always require a password prompt upon reboot.

As I understand it, the password / key for these SEDs is generally stored inside a special `ATA password` field in `BIOS`. When `OS` boots, the disk looks to this password / key and decrypts, and remains decrypted as long as `OS` is in session. But am not sure whether it prompts the user for a password and does a match upon reboot or decrypts without any intervention..

Currently, I require the disk to not require any password prompt upon system boot, it should take it from the `BIOS`. I know that if the PC gets stolen, then data is exposed, but at least I want to ensure that disk theft will not cause data exposure.

If this is not possible, that a `SED` will always ask for a password prompt when `OS` boots, would it help if the `key` be placed in a `TPM` instead, assuming that is possible, not sure if it would make a difference though.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the point of having an encrypted disk that decrypts automatically on boot. That leaves no security whatsoever. Anyone with the machine has the data.

Comment: @Tetsujin Correct. At the moment, though, that is not a concern and appropriate procedures are in place to take care of that scenario. What is of concern is the data on disk, which if itself stolen, or somehow obtained, should not reveal its data without the actual system being in place.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Only as far as the machine allows to read it. Which is generally the idea of TPM-based automatic unlocking that BitLocker does: the original OS hopefully won't let outsiders log in without knowing the Windows password, and trying to boot a different OS prevents auto-unlocking.